# Если ничего не писать в текстовое поле, то ничего не сохраняется Django

Tags: python, html, django

Возникла проблема, что при сохранении текстового поля (тоесть модель со значением TextField) криво выводит текст (не в самом поле, а рядом), а если ничего не писать в поле, то он не сохраняет данные введённые ранее.[image: Тоесть он вот так его сохраняет]

Это именно происходит с текстовым полем, модель с типом IntegerField сохраняет всё нормально.
И это происходит когда в html, форма (поле) стоит в input. Если отдельно, то всё сохраняет нормально.

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from users.views import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime, date


class character(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Дата изменения, mm/dd/gg", auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, 
    blank=True, null=True)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    # description - описание
    character_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null = True)
    worldview = models.TextField(blank=True)
    nameperson = models.TextField(blank=True)
    lvlcharacter = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True)
```

views.py

```
from urllib import request
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import character
from .forms import CharacterForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import random
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404

def edit(request, id):
character_edit = get_object_or_404(character, id=id)
if character_edit.author != request.user:
    return redirect('index')
form = CharacterForm(request.POST or None, instance=character_edit)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(commit=False)
    auto_correct(form.instance)
    form.save()
character_edit = get_object_or_404(character, id=id)
form = CharacterForm(instance=character_edit)
context = {
    'form': form,
}    
return render(request, "main.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import character, User
from django.forms import modelform_factory

#class CharacterForm (forms.ModelForm):
#character_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '40'}))

#class Meta:
    #model = character
    #fields = '__all__'

CharacterForm = modelform_factory(character, exclude=('author',))
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Страница заполнения</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mysite.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.htmlbook.ru/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" 
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F5DEB3" link="#8B4513" vlink="#A52A2A"> 
<!--<div><img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/rpg/images/8/80/Pathfinder_RPG.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20100606105213&path-prefix=ru" alt="Лого pathfiner"  width="400" height="150" style="margin: 0px"> </div>
    
<!--<h1>{{form.date}}<h2>-->
<form action="" method="POST" class="post-form"> {% csrf_token %}






   <style> 
    .tableparams_one
    {
        
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px auto;
        bottom: 120px;
    }  
    .general-input {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: inherit;
        outline: none;
        padding:0;
        margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
        
      }
</style>
<table class="tableparams_one"style=margin-left:px  style=padding:0px>
<tr>  <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/rpg/images/8/80/Pathfinder_RPG.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20100606105213&path-prefix=ru" alt="Лого pathfiner"  width="500" height="150" > </tr>  
<tr> <td> <input style = "width:250px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" {{form.character_name}}  <br> Имя персонажа </td> 
<td> <input style = "width:200px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" id={{form.worldview}} <br> Мировоззрение  </td>
<td> <input style = "width:200px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" id={{form.nameperson}} <br> Игрок </td>
<td> <input style = "width:100px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" id={{form.eye}} <br> Глаза </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input style= "width:200px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" id={{form.lvlcharacter}} <br> Уровень персонажа </td>
<td> <input style = "width:200px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" id={{form.thedeity}} <br> Божество </td>
<td> <input style = "width:200px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" id={{form.homeland}} <br> Родина </td>
<td> <input style = "width:100px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" id={{form.hair}} <br> Волосы </td>
<td> <input style = "width:50px" type="text" class = "general-input"size="2" id={{form.weight}} <br> Вес </td>

</tr>    
<button>Сохранить</button> 




    
    
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Если написать вот так: {{character_name}} без input, то всё работает

Comment: Не сохраняет пустое значение скорее всего потому, что вы не указали параметр null=True в описании поля.

Comment: @strawdog В том то и дело, что всё сохраняет в базе данных, но после отправки данных текстовые поля автоматически не вставляют значения в поле, а выводятся рядом и при повторном сохранении поле считается пустым (якобы не заполнил). Т.е. при повторном сохранении в бд отправлется пустое поле.